# Android notification which shows as text in the lower half

Tags: android, notifications

this question is really dump I'd say but what are the notifications called that only show a quick text information in the lower half of the screen with a gray background?

They, for example, show the remaining time until the alarm will ring in the standard Android alarm application.
I just wasn't able to find them because I have no idea how to describe it properly xD

Hopefully, you guys know what I am talking about, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean [Clock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.deskclock), what you are looking at is a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) message.

```
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

Comment: Oh yeah that sounds like a good class, thank you so much :) I will accept your answer as soon as I can